# Real vs True Positives

Tags: classification, precision-recall, confusion-matrix, information-retrieval

[Wikipedia defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) TPR (True Positive Rate) as  $\frac{\text{TP}}{P}$

where:

- $\text{TP}$ = # of **true** positives
- $\text{P}$ = # of **real** positives

This confuses me.

I thought:

- $\text{TP}$ is supposed to be the number of **true** **predicted** (estimated) positives.
- $\text{P}$ is supposed to be the **total** number of positives.

What does "**real**" mean here? Is this terminology actually common in practice?

[image]

Comment: I think 'real' is used because it's possible that there are positives that we don't know about, and perhaps never will know about. We estimate them with a gold standard or a test, but it's an estimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real positives are the positive samples that were classified as positives $TP$ and positive samples that were classified as negatives $FN$:

$$
P = TP + FN
$$

so it’s all the positive samples in the data.

Comment: Does the Wikipedia entry need "real" as a modifier of positives and negatives?  I see that there have been many recent edits to this Wikipedia entry to try to make it understandable and consistent.  Maybe an expert could edit out the two uses of "real" in the sidebar.  I don't know how to edit Wikipedia entries.  More important, this entry is about machine learning and this is not my expertise.

Comment: @DianaPetitti yes it does. There are *real positives* (you predict if the weather is sunny, so real positives are the sunny days in your data), and *predicted positives* (the days marked by your algorithm as "sunny"), true positives are cases where they agree.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.  When this table is created for medical testing/classification, the "real" is omitted.

Comment: @DianaPetitti it should be obvious from the context, but I guess adding "real" makes it more explicit.